# Cake PHP validation, change incoming $data

Tags: cakephp, variables, validation, cakephp-2.1

I got a problem with my cake validation.
The user enters e.g. "20€" in a form field and I only want to get the number "20" with stripped out Euro-sign. But the validation methods only allow checking if something is what it´s supposed to be.

I´m about to create a function in my rule-set but I´m struggling going further because what the function returns in cake context is either true or false, not a modified variable like I need ...

```
'rule-3' => array(
    'rule'    => 'checkEuro',
    'message' => 'don´t need one because it should be a conversion only :-('
)

public function checkEuro($data) {
    $data = str_replace('&#8364;','',$data);
    return preg_replace('/[^0-9]/','', html_entity_decode($data));
}
```

I hope you can help.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only need to store the *amount* itself inside the database and *not* the euro-sign, you should *strip* the Euro-sign before validating.

You can do this inside the [`beforeValidate()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html#beforevalidate) callback of your model;

```
public function beforeValidate(array $options = array())
{
    if (!empty($this->data[$this->alias]['FIELDNAME']) {
        // Strip the euro-sign
        // NOTE: should also take plain, non-entity € into account here?
        $this->data[$this->alias]['FIELDNAME'] = str_replace(
            '&#8364;', '', $this->data[$this->alias]['FIELDNAME']
        );
    }

    return parent::beforeValidate($options);
}
```

(Of course, replace `FIELDNAME` with the actual fieldname)

After stripping the currency-symbol, validate the value using the [`decimal`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#Validation%3a%3adecimal) or [`numeric`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#Validation%3a%3anumeric) validation rule

**note**
If you *do* want to store the value *including* the currency-symbol, use the core [`money`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#Validation%3a%3amoney) validation rule.

Comment: Wow! Exactly what I needed. I swapped the HTML mask with the "€" and it works superb :-)

Comment: Glad I could help! Good luck with your project